# How to bind a boolean to toggle a Button's Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, button

I have a `Button`...

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" />
```

I'd like to bind a `CanClick` boolean to this somehow. When `CanClick` is `false` then the `Click` event shouldn't fire...

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

I'd use a binding to the `Button`'s `IsEnabled` property.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanBeClicked}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

For this you could just use a [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) instead (by binding [`Button.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx) to a [`Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx)), it will disable the button if [`CanExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) is `false` (you may need to use the [`CanExecuteChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx) event to make the button aware of a change to `CanExecute`).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to bind a property `CanClick` to the `Button` control's `IsEnabled` property. This way, when `CanClick` is `false`, `IsEnabled` will also be `false`. A disabled button will not fire the `Click` event.

```
// ... UserControl code-behind ...
private bool mCanClick = false;
public bool CanClick
{
    get { return mCanClick; }
}

// ... UserControl XAML ...
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

...

    <Button CanClick="{Binding CanClick}" Click="Button_Click" />

...

</UserControl>
```